# Python script "executing file" forever

Tags: python, qr-code

Here is my script:

```
def encodage(message):
    """
    begins our binary qrcode with the type of the message:
    binary, numeric or alphanumeric (string)
    """
    qrcode = []



    if type(message) == str: #string
        qrcode = [0,0,1,0] + qrcode

    else: 
        if type(message) == list: #list can contain numeric and alphanumeric
            if type(message[0]) == int:
                bit = True

                while bit:
                    for n in message:
                        if (n != 0) and (n != 1): #verifying if binary
                            bit = False
                if bit:
                    qrcode = [0,1,0,0] + qrcode
                else:
                    qrcode = [0,0,0,1] + qrcode

            if type(message[0]) == str:
                qrcode = [0,0,1,0] + qrcode
    return qrcode
```

I think what it does is clear enough. When I run it with the following:

```
message = [0,1,1,1,1]

print(encodage(message))
```

No answer is given, it just turns forever.

I think the problem comes from my weird binary test loop (it works for `message = "salut"`).

What do you think ? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Why not try putting some print statements in there and see where the code goes?

Comment: @darthbith I would consider this as cheating... `:)`

Comment: Hint: Your `while` loop will never stop if `message` contains only `0`s and `1`s. Step through it manually to see.

Comment: since all of the numbers are 0 or 1, `bit` is never set to `False`, so you `while` loop will run forever.

Comment: I put a `print(n)` on line 20. You were right, thank you, and as I suspected the list elements are read endlessly, `bit` being always `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no benefit for the while-loop. Just remove the `while`. It makes also no sense to add an empty list to the result:

```
def encodage(message):
    """
    begins our binary qrcode with the type of the message:
    binary, numeric or alphanumeric (string)
    """
    if isinstance(message, str):
        qrcode = [0,0,1,0]
    elif isinstance(message, list):
        if isinstance(message[0], int):
            # verifying if binary
            bit = all(n in (0, 1) for n in message)
            qrcode = [0,1,0,0] if bit else [0,0,0,1]
        elif isinstance(message[0], str):
            qrcode = [0,0,1,0]
        else:
            qrcode = []
    else:
        qrcode = []
return qrcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you see your condition?

```
message = [0,1,1,1,1]

bit = True
while bit:
  for n in message:
    if (n != 0) and (n != 1): #verifying if binary
     bit = False
```

this

```
if (n != 0) and (n != 1): #verifying if binary
```

will always return `False` thus looping forever, just compare your input (message) with this if statement and see if it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to several remarks, here's a correction:

```
    if type(message) == list:
        if type(message[0]) == int:
            bit = True

            for n in message:
                if (n != 0) and (n != 1):
                    bit = False
```

Thank you all.